# Meteor app breaks after version 0.8.3

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteorite, atmosphere

My app was working well with version 0.8.3, but I tried to update to version 0.9.2.2 because the terminal says this:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
error: no such package: 'spin'
error: no such package: 'momentjs'
error: no such package: 'iron-router-progress'
error: no such package: 'zurb-foundation'
error: no such package: 'accounts-entry'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I tried meteor update and the terminal printed this:

```
This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your current package constraints.
```

I checked the release file in .meteor and it says 0.8.3, so I created a new app added all the packages that I had and paste in the new app all the code that I had.

When I first tried to enter in the new app the console printed this error:

```
<deprecated> [Router] 'before' is deprecated. Please use 'onBeforeAction' instead. Error
```

I used 'onBeforeAction' instead of 'before', and I tried again to enter in the new app, and then nothing: the server and the console doesn't print any error and in the browser instead of my data it shows [object Object]

I'm completely lost, so any help with this it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect using [mrt migrate-app](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/updating-to-090/) would have been better. I had similar problems but I just manually edited my `.meteor/release` file.

As for the iron router issues, it's likely you were using a pretty dated version of the package. Just make sure to read through [the docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md) and fix things as needed.

The most likely cause of the `[object Object]` output is the use of `yield` in your layout template(s). Make sure it looks like `{{> yield}}`.